# Reverse engineering a node app that used zeit/pkg to "compile" it

Tags: javascript, node.js, reverse-engineering, v8, zeit-pkg

I have an app (that I believe has malware in it, but I wish to confirm before I go ahead and use it) that has been compiled/packaged using [Zeit's PKG](https://github.com/zeit/pkg).

It seems to use v8's snapshot feature to obfuscate the code... any way to reverse this? I know it compiled node in the exe, but I'm new to programming and reverse engineering.

Where do I start with reverse engineering this thing? Thanks!

Comment: If you believe an app has malware in it, you shouldn't use it!

Comment: But I can't prove it to my friends, so they continue to use it. I want to help them see that it's malicious.